# Clipping raster with polygon for band-by-band output using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, shapefile, clip

How do you clip a raster image with a polygon shapefile so that the output is multiple clipped rasters, each one a band (i.e., clipped raster band 1, band 2, and so on)?

I've tried the clip tool for raster, but that doesn't output each individual band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clip the raster with your polygon and save the clipped multi-band image.

Then use the 'lookup' took in ArcGIS to separately save the different bands from your clipped multi-band image.

**Update**

1. Find the Look up function found under the spatial analyst toolbox:

[image]

2. Right-click on the tool, and select t he 'Batch' option.It first comes with only 1 row but you can add as many rows as the number of bands you have in your image, using the '+' button on the right. Before you click 'OK' make sure you specified processing extent and coordinate systems using the 'Environments' button at the bottom of the Lookup GUI
   [image]
3. Use extract by mask function (you can use the batch processing here too) to clip all the output rasters according to your chosen polygon feature.

Comment: I tried the clip tool, and it's a single raster image output. I don't know what band it's associated with. I also tried to use the Lookup tool, and it says the input file is not within the defined domain. Can you possibly re-explain the steps I should follow please?

Comment: How many bands do you have? you can always first use the lookup then, extract the multiple single bands with your polygon.

Comment: I have 8 bands associated with the WorldView-2 imagery. I'll try out your instructions, thank you!

Comment: Make sure you set the Environment settings the "lookup" function and the "composite bands" function particularly require that to be set, otherwise the process fails with error 99999 (don't remember the exact number of the nines :) )